# Create a custom html extension that will work like a ListBoxFor but output checkboxes instead?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create (or even better find) a custom html extension method that works in a similar manor to the ListBoxFor but renders a group of checkboxes instead of a select multiple.

What is the best way of going about this?  I am curious how the ListBoxFor method works, when it is only passed an expression and an enumerable of SelectListItems, which only have the default items selected.  It is not passed the model, so how does it know when to select the correct items (somehow it seems able to do that)?  Also, how does it write html attributes based on an anonymous object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided any details and specific example of what you are trying to achieve. You haven't provided any source code you have tried so far in order to solve the problem you are having. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow please do so in order to make your question more meaningful and focused on a specific problem.

Anyway, here's an example. Let's suppose that you have defined a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller that will populate this view model with values and hopefully in the POST action obtain the selected values in the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SelectedValues = new[] { "1", "3" },
            Values = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // model.SelectedValues will contain the ids of items that were checked
        // in the checkbox list
    }
}
```

and then a view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.SelectedValues, Model.Values, null)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

OK, so far so good. The last part is to try to implement this `CheckBoxListFor` helper. Obviously depending on your specific requirements and context there could be many possible ways to do this (see my remark in the beginning of the answer). So here's just some sample implementation that could get you started:

```
public static class HtmlExtnsions
{
    public static IHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        var values = GetModelStateValue(htmlHelper.ViewData, fullHtmlFieldName, typeof(string[]));
        if (values == null)
        {
            values = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullHtmlFieldName);
        }

        if (values != null)
        {
            var collection =
                from object value in values as IEnumerable
                select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(collection, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                item.Selected = ((item.Value != null) ? hashSet.Contains(item.Value) : hashSet.Contains(item.Text));
                list.Add(item);
            }
            selectList = list;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in selectList)
        {
            var checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
            checkbox.Attributes["type"] = "checkbox";
            checkbox.Attributes["name"] = fullHtmlFieldName;
            checkbox.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
            checkbox.GenerateId(fullHtmlFieldName);
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                checkbox.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
            }
            sb.Append(checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            sb.Append(item.Value);
        }

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    private static object GetModelStateValue(ViewDataDictionary viewData, string key, Type destinationType)
    {
        ModelState modelState;
        if (viewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out modelState) && modelState.Value != null)
        {
            return modelState.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was so vague, but thanks for your answer, I have learnt a lot from it already.  In particular I did not know about TagBuilder nor htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval.

Comment: @zod, haven't you looked at the ASP.NET MVC source code? I would recommend you to do so in order to learn how standard helpers are implemented. It will allow you to gather a much better understanding of the framework and make it easier to implement custom helpers.

Comment: This generates the same id for every check box, which (I think) is wrong, so I removed that one line (don’t think they need ids anyway).  It also does not use the html attributes, but I hardly needed that, so removed it.  Otherwise it is excellent (I wrapped the whole thing in a div, gave that a class (hard coded) (maybe I should give that the id as well), and put each checkbox and text pair in a label tag).  Thanks very much.